# DPDK 18.11 HW checksum support for X722 NIC?

Tags: dpdk

I am running dpdk-stable-18.11.8 on Centos 7, targeting an Intel X722 NIC.

I want ipv4 and udp header checksums to be calculated by hardware, so I set the device configuration to:

```
struct rte_eth_conf local_port_conf;
memset(&local_port_conf, 0, sizeof(struct rte_eth_conf));
local_port_conf.rxmode.split_hdr_size = 0;
local_port_conf.txmode.mq_mode = ETH_MQ_TX_NONE;
local_port_conf.txmode.offloads  = DEV_TX_OFFLOAD_OUTER_UDP_CKSUM | DEV_TX_OFFLOAD_OUTER_IPV4_CKSUM;
rte_eth_dev_configure(0,1,1,&local_port_conf);
```

rte_eth_dev_configure returns:
0xffffffea (-22)

Does this mean that DPDK 18.11 doesn't support checksum offload to the X722 NIC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DEV_TX_OFFLOAD_OUTER_IPV4_CKSUM is used for outer tunnelling packet, for which X710 has to be loaded with DDP. If the intent is for normal packet `DEV_TX_OFFLOAD_IPV4_CKSUM` is to be used.

Note: right way of configuring any DPDK port is to first fetch capability by `rte_eth_dev_info_get`. Then check `dev_info.tx_offload_capa & DEV_TX_OFFLOAD_IPV4_CKSUM`, if present configure.

Comment: Thank you. I now use: local_port_conf.txmode.offloads  = DEV_TX_OFFLOAD_IPV4_CKSUM  | DEV_TX_OFFLOAD_UDP_CKSUM; The IPV4 checksum is correct but tcpdump shows that udp checksum is zero. Any idea why please?

Comment: I am further confused by the dpdk documentation https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/prog_guide/mbuf_lib.html that says: "set out_udp checksum to pseudo header using rte_ipv4_phdr_cksum()". Is this really correct or should it be set using rte_ipv4_udptcp_cksum()?  I tried p_udp_hdr->dgram_cksum = rte_ipv4_phdr_cksum((const ipv4_hdr*)(ptMbuf->l3_len), ptMbuf->ol_flags); but that gave me a segmentation fault.

Comment: Hi @DavidA the information shared in the site works. One needs to follow the steps shared in the link you have shared if you need HW to calculate the checksum for outgoing packets. The current ticket is based on configuration issue. If you feel the configuration issue is resolved please upvote and accept the same